# Is there a "load sequence" tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tagging

Some (La)TeX answers indicate load sequence preferences. Is there a tag for those questions?

Comment: Because the tag goes with the question, not the answer, I'm seeing another layer to the issue. The Q'or may not know of that issue. The load-order info shows up in the Answers. Thus, something current along this line may be a solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before

Maybe a Comment with simply 'load order' will suffice so as to find those discussions readily (as if "tagged").  Is there a Community-approved preference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That I know of, this area has not had enough questions for someone to tag questions in a useful way. Tags are 'dynamic' in the sense anyone can tag questions as they like. So there is nothing to stop people using [load-order](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/load-order) or similar.

Answer (score 2):

"answers indicate" is the wrong approach. Tags belong to the question and should not be added because one of the answers discovers a problem or uses a special package.

Therefor the suggested edits

- https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/158144
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/158068
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/157927
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/157890

have been rightfully rejected.

Otherwise we end up with pervert situations like https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/443821/revisions where a tag is added to a question just because one in five answers uses it.

Comment: This confirms the follow-up comment to the Q.  So, we just leave the pernicious "load order" issue as a research project for the newbies and experienced alike, or we use the comment section to render the issue a bit more findable?

Comment: Further study and discussion indicates that "load order" is more document-specific than general.  That being the case, there's no "general" tag or commenting that's going to provide much in the way of assistance.